# XAF - Changing value of a PropertyEditor

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I'm learning XAF and I want to know how to access the value of a PropertyEditor to change it. I want to take the value from a PropertyEditor and put that value into another PropertyEditor's value. My code is like this:

```
Property Editor reserva = (PropertyEditor)((DetailView)View).FindItem("Reserva"); //This is a custom object
PropertyEditor dni = (PropertyEditor)((DetailView)View).FindItem("Dni");//This is a simple text editor
PropertyEditor dniReserva = (PropertyEditor)reserva.View.FindItem("Dni");//This is a variable from the custom object
dni.PropertyValue = dniReserva.ControlValue;
```

This does not work, any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about copying the value of a non persistent property to another non persistent property? Because in any other case I believe there are more suitable ways to copy a value, working with the actual properties ([here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18699) is usefull answer to help you with that)and not the editors.
If however you actually need this,I believe you could create a ViewController and use the PropertyEditor properties like this

```
        foreach (PropertyEditor editor in ((DetailView)View).GetItems<PropertyEditor>())
        {
            var control = editor.Control as IntegerEdit;
            if (control != null)
            {
                    if (editor.Id == "Id" || editor.Caption == "Id")
                    {
                        control.Enabled = false;
                    }           
            }
        }
```

Comment: You help me to understand what I wanted, thanks. The link was very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Each property editor in XAF reads value from the specific property of the business object. This specificity reduces your task to copying the value of the specific property to another one.

In the ViewController, you can access the current business object using the [View.CurrentObject](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/DevExpressExpressAppView_CurrentObjecttopic) property. Once the property is updated with an appropriate value, the new value will immediately appear in the property editor.

If the business object does not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (for example, if you are using Entity Framework Code First), you may also want to call the [View.Refresh](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/DevExpressExpressAppView_Refreshtopic(r7XZdQ)) method to make new values appear in the editor.